# How to create a custom control containing two different controls interacting with each other?

Tags: wpf, class, custom-controls

I already have made a `CustomControl` containing two classes. One derived from `Label` and the other derived from `TextBox`. But I can't make one communicate with the other. For example when the user presses the Enter key on the `TextBox`, whatever the text is inside it, must be copied in the `Label`.
Like this pseudo-code:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Key == Key.Return)
                {
                    TheLabel.text = TheTextBox.text;
                }
            }
```

But I can't manipulate one control from inside another. Because each one is in it's separate class like this:

```
public class TheLabel : Label{...}
```

and

```
public class TheTextBox : TextBox{...}
```

**SO**
Is there a special way to create a `CustomControl`, containing two or more controls, communicating with each other ?

Comment: Don't you have a `Content` or `Text` property on your custom controls? If not you just have to expose the ones that are defined in the base class

Comment: Its WPF, why not just derive from `UIElement`, and construct everything in `Xaml`, why do you need derived classes of `TextBox` and `Label`, I'm pretty sure you will be able to do anything you need in Xaml using `Styles`, and any code behind you do need will be in you single usercontrol class

Answer (score 1):

You can use two methods.

First, you can employ composition, in which you create a class that combines both of the individual controls:

```
    public class CompositeClass {
              private TheLabel  _label;
              private TheTextBox _textbox;
}
```

Alternatively, you can pass in a reference to the object for one class into the other, so that it can manipulate that object in the event handler:

public class TheLabel : Label {

```
   TheTextBox _textbox;

  public TheLabel(TheTextBox t) {
       _textbox = t;
  }
```

}

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot !
I will test it and post feedback ;)

Answer (score 0):

You link the information by using a [DependancyProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) on each of the custom controls. Then each dependency property will also subscribe to a change event. When the data is changed in one, the event will fire and you can do the appropriate processing in the other control as needed.